# После нажатия на кнопку, нужно добавлять в переменную damage рандом. числа и суммировать их

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400+200+100")

credit = 0
damage = 0

def random_damage():
    damage = random.randrange(30, 90)
    print(damage)

btn_one = Button(text="btn", width="20", command=random_damage).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Не могу сделать так, чтобы рандом. числа суммировались и сохранялись в переменной

Comment: damage += random.randrange(30, 90)

Comment: Я пробовал. Вылазит ошибка.

Comment: Возможно поможет прописать в функции: global damage

Comment: Вы хоть пытались код скопировать и попробовать прописать это всё у себя?

Comment: Нет, доступа к компьютеру нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400+200+100")

credit = 0
damage = 0

def random_damage():
    global damage
    if damage == 0:
        damage = random.randrange(30, 90)
        print(damage)
    elif damage > 0:
        dam = random.randrange(30, 90)
        damage += dam
        print(damage)

btn_one = Button(text="btn", width="20", command= lambda: random_damage()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Если у вас была проблема с тем, что функция не выполнялась, то вы забыли скобки после `random_damage` при нажатии кнопки. Так же когда присваиваете функцию кнопке, то после `command =` лучше прописывать `lambda: функция()`, это нужно чтобы функция не использовалась сразу при создании окна.

Comment: Вы наверное не так поняли) После нажатия на кнопку выводится первое число в консоль. При повторном, нажатии выводится второе число, но эти два числа не суммируются. Как сделать так, чтобы все числа после нажатия кнопки сразу же суммировались? (Я извиняюсь если как-то криво объяснил)

Comment: @andromeda, исправил код под ваши нужды. Только он выводит сразу суммированный урон, без промежуточного(нанесенного после второго нажатия кнопки)

Comment: вылазит ошибка.

Comment: Так, сейчас буду смотреть что за ошибку допустил

Comment: Жалуется на if damage == 0:

Comment: Исправил. Работает